# React-Native Global Dialogs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a dialog that can be open on any screens. I've tried to search and I can't seem to find how to architect it properly.

In my current architecture, all of my screens are passing to my `BaseScreen` HOC. It adds my custom widget that is provided on all screens. But when I put my dialog there, I can't find a way to call it from a specific screen.

**BaseScreen:**

```
function BaseScreen(WrappedComponent) {
   return class BaseScreen extends WrappedComponent {
      render() {
         return (
          //add custom widgets here
          {super.render()} //to insert the specific layout for the current screen/wrapped component
         );
      }
   }
}
```

**Custom Screen:**

```
function CustomScreen extends React.Component {
    //more codes here
}

export default BaseScreen(CustomScreen);
```

How can I insert a global dialog on my `BaseScreen` and call it from the `CustomScreen`? (Loading Dialog, Error Dialog, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. in `BaseScreen` let add state for dialog. then add a method `showDialog` to control show and hide dialog.

```
const BaseScreen = WrappedComponent => class extends React.Component{
      state = {
         showDialog: true,
      }

      showDialog = (bool= true) => {
         this.setState({showDialog: bool});
      }

      render() {
         return (
            <View>
               //Code for dialog here
               <WrappedComponent showDialog={this.showDialog}/>
            </View>
         );
      }
   }
```

in `CustomScreen` you can show and hide dialog with `showDialog` func from props.

Comment: I'm using my `BaseScreen` as an HOC. This is the other way around, passing props to children. I'm looking for an architecture on how to to it properly. Thanks by the way, appreciated.